# SQL statement will not work in PHP but works in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Found a few similar questions, but nothing exactly like this...  So here goes...

So this SQL statement works perfectly when I paste it into a PHPMyAdmin SQL window, but it returns zero results (no error) when run as a PHP mysql_query statement:

```
SELECT  distinct action_detail2
FROM    stats_tracking
WHERE   date_entered >= '2013-05-08 00:00:00' AND
        date_entered <= '2013-05-08 23:59:59'  AND
        action_detail1 != '10.0.0.1'
ORDER BY    action_detail2
```

You would think it would error if there was something wrong with the syntax.  As you can see, I'm trying to return all entries from a specific day. And that works perfectly on PHPMyAdmin.  Just returns 0 results in a "mysql_query" call.

Here's the code:

```
// Fix date entries
$fixFrom = explode("-", $_GET['from']);
$FROM = $fixFrom[2] . "-" . $fixFrom[0] . "-" . $fixFrom[1];
$fixTo = explode("-", $_GET['to']);
$TO = $fixTo[2] . "-" . $fixTo[0] . "-" . $fixTo[1];

// Build SQL statement
$SQL_Centers = "
    SELECT      distinct(action_detail2)
    FROM        stats_tracking
    WHERE       date_entered >= '" . $FROM . " 00:00:00' AND
                date_entered <= '" . $TO . " 23:59:59'  AND
                action_detail1 != '10.0.0.1'
    ORDER BY    action_detail2
";

$resultCenters = mysql_query($SQL_Centers); // Run the actual query.

$dataCount_Centers=mysql_num_rows($resultCenters); // Get the count of rows, just in case we need it.

echo $dataCount_Centers;
```

This is returning a count of 0.  NO ERROR.  Later in the code I convert all data output to JSON - and all other queries work.  This shows no JSON records as well.  Again.. NO ERRORS.  They're all running through the same DB connection.. etc.  Clearly this statement is resulting in no records being returned.

I ECHO'd the SQL statement, then cut and pasted it from Firebug to this question.  Then I pasted it into PHPMyAdmin SQL - and ran it.  Worked perfectly.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Provide us your PHP code

Comment: pls show your php code for the mysql query..

Comment: Edited to show code.  Thanks.

Comment: are you connected to the correct dbspace? what is error output?

Comment: There is no error.  The connection is the same - all SQL statements in the code share the same DB connection and database connection - and they all work.  This one is running - with no errors being returned.

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: @Gumbo You're right.  This is still in early dev stages.  But thanks.. that's important to remember!

Answer (score 2):

> Just returns 0 results in a "mysql_query" call.

That means you have an error in your query. `0` is a `False` value.

So, the next step would be to find out what the error is. To do that, print the result of `mysql_error()`.

You should also migrate your code from `mysql_*` to `mysqli` or `PDO` as the old `mysql_*` methods will be removed from PHP. See [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) in the PHP manual for more information.

Comment: Actually.. it returns zero results.  I.e., the JSON object shows 0 records.  I tried echoing mysql_error() and it did not contain anything.  Yeah.. msqli is the next move.  But for now, this is still a mystery.

Comment: What do you mean by this _the JSON object shows 0 records_? There isn't a single mention of JSON in your code. Please update your question with all the _relevant_ parts of your code.

Comment: At the end of the code - I convert the results arrays to JSON.  I will edit the question again.

Comment: Add `echo mysql_error();` _after_ the `mysql_query()` call and then update your question with any output.

Comment: There is no output.   I tried that.  Nothing is returned in the echo of mysql_error();

Answer (score 0):

First..I would say, please show your php code, meanwhile, you can try this

```
SELECT  distinct action_detail2 as "ACTION_DETAIL2" 
    FROM    stats_tracking
    WHERE   date_entered >= '2013-05-08 00:00:00' AND
            date_entered <= '2013-05-08 23:59:59'  AND
            action_detail1 != '10.0.0.1'
    ORDER BY    action_detail2
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is several years old (mysqli is now the new normal), but I have had a similar problem. A query worked if I pasted it into phpmyadmin, but not from a PHP script. I had no errors and got absolutely no indication something was wrong other than the lack of updating in my database. So, after deleting and rebuilding my database table by hand (ugh...), it turns out I was using a multi-line query, something the standard mysqli_query doesn't support. Example:

```
mysqli_query($connection, "SET @x = 0; UPDATE table SET someValue = (@x=@x*2) WHERE someID = 4;");
```

If you are doing something similar, try using mysqli_multi_query instead:

```
mysqli_multi_query($connection, "SET @x = 0; UPDATE table SET someValue = (@x=@x*2) WHERE someID = 4;");
```

... something which now seems embarrassingly obvious. :)

Hopefully this helps someone else in the future!